# Enable “Do Not Allow Windows Messenger to be run” group policy using power shell script

Tags: powershell, scripting, policy, messenger

I want to perform following tasks on Windows 2008 r2 machine -

1) Enable “Do Not Allow Windows Messenger to be run”.
2) Enable “Do Not Automatically Start Windows Messenger Initially”.

To do this, group policy exists on the following path "Open gpedit.msc >Expand Computer configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows components > Windows Messenger"

Need to do this using PowerShell script. How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In reality, you can easily control this via the regedit in either:

```
HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\
```

or

```
HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\
```

This would work, AFAIK:

```
Set-GPRegistryValue -Name "WindowsMessenger" -Key "PathToYourTheKeyYoudNeed" -ValueName "xxx" -Type String -Value "YourValue"
```

This also works with

```
-type DWORD
```

Now, I sadly can not really check, where the necessary keys are located, that you would need to control because I do not have any 2008r2 in my company environment.

Hope I could help!

Comment: I also could not found the key path for the WindowsMessenger key! I searched for it on google and found key path as "HKCU:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Messenger\Client" which does not exist on my machine!

Comment: Now, this is just some random idea, but you COULD try setting it once manually in gpedit. See if this creates the value you need. Once it is created, you can touch it easily in powershell. If this is no possibility for you, you would have to basically craft and force your way through by manipulating the regedit tree with PoSh commands. This is totally possible but not easy at all, I personally avoid manipulating RegEdits on my own.